# Compiling lambdas and invoking delegates on the device in Monotouch 

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, xamarin.ios, expression-trees

I am currently porting a .NET codebase in MonoTouch and I'm currently working on a method that receives an `Expression<T>`. I'm trying to compile it, and then dynamically invoke it.

Here's what I did:

```
// Here's an example of what I could receive
Expression<Action<int>> expression = (a => Console.WriteLine (a * 2));

// And here's what I'm trying to do to invoke it
expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(6);
```

This works fine in the iOS Simulator, the result "12" is printed in my console. But then I tried it on an iPad, and I received the following exception.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at System.Linq.jvm.Runner.CreateDelegate ()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression.Compile ()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Action`1[System.Int32]].Compile ()
   at TestSolution2.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options)
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not familiar with System.Linq.Expressions, but presumably it involves runtime code generation.

There is no JIT in iOS, all code must be compiled ahead-of-time. The same restriction does not apply in the simulator, hence your code runs there.

See [here](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Limitations#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation).

The `Compile()` method is not supported on the iOS device, since the device prevents the JIT engine from running.   Compile itself is implemented using System.Reflection.Emit and this in turns requires a functioning JIT.    So the above code would never wor kwith expression trees.

Comment: I'd guess the OS doesn't prevent the generation of the code, but prevents marking it as executable. Of course the net result is the same.